# Rewrite URL for Search + Special Characters / Umlaute

Tags: url-rewriting, search, htmlspecialchars-decode

I want prettier search urls, like `/suche/Danach+suche+ich/`
So here is my code:

```
add_filter("rewrite_rules_array", function($rules) {

    $newRules = array();
    $newRules["suche/(.+)/?$"] = 'index.php?s=$matches[1]';

    $merged = array_merge($newRules, $rules);

    return $merged;
});
```

`/?s=Testbeitrag` works

`/suche/Testbeitrag` same result, nice

`/?s=Ümlautetest` works, nice!

`/suche/Ümlautetest` doesn't work

I still get to the right page, but there are no posts printed out–

[image]

.

---

EDIT:
it appears that the issue is in my `archive.php`

I want to change the number of posts for all queries going to `archive.php` in order to prepare infinite scroll mechanics.

```
global $query_string;

$posts = query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=150'); 
// the main $wp_query doesn't seem to have "numberposts", so "posts_per_page" it is
```

When I comment out this line, the `/suche/Ümlautetest` gives me the expected results.

But Why does this line only affects the results with `/suche/Ümlautetest`?

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Incorrect results? 404?

Comment: I still get to the right page, but there are no posts printed out–

Comment: I tried your exact code and didn't have any trouble. I created a post just with the title "Ü", then tried ?s=Ü and /suche/Ü and they both returned the same results, with the "Ü" post at the top.

Comment: Okay– See the edit please.

Comment: ? Nothing's changed?

Comment: Lesson learned: first change, then comment – Now it's there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69427/discussion-between-kater-louis-and-jacob-peattie).

Comment: The search query doesn't seem to get `urldecode`d when using `query_posts()` another reason to [never use query_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/39152).

Comment: What method would you suggest to increase the number of posts to 150 for queries going to `archive.php`

Comment: [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). Also, the idea of infinite scroll is just to load the posts you need when you need them, not to load them all and just hide them.

Comment: I know, the team decided to not go the AJAX route; and since the images of hidden elements aren't loaded, the only "additional weight" is a bit more HTML.

Comment: Don't use `query_posts`.

Comment: Can I place the `pre_get_posts` hook in the `archive.php`? I really only want to change the query for `archive.php`

Comment: [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Comment: Okay, it appears it has to go in themes `functions.php` – and according to https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts `is_archive()` is not available.. I tried it and can confirm; `is_archive()` is ignored.

Comment: Hm, increase archive posts still doesn't work. But that is another matter–
 One of you nice guys can answer the question and get the points :)